# REPL for ocamldebug?

Tags: ocaml

One of the things that I miss from GHC (Haskell) when using OCaml is that there is no unified debugger/REPL. The debugger and the REPL are completely separate, which is crazy! You can't think of a random function call and execute it in the running process, like you can in ghci.

Any tips, workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REPL for Ocaml which is not debuggable, it is the `ocaml` command.

You might also use `ocamldebug` on `ocaml`, but I'm not sure it would help you.

The `ocamldebug` debugger is mostly used (on your application compiled with `ocamlc`) as you would use `gdb` for C.